# Lambda creating ENI everytime it is invoked: Hitting limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My Lambda accesses resources on my VPC so as instructed in the documentation I've given the Lambda a role to create network interfaces. I was under the assumption that the ENI is reused but looks like every invocation is creating a new ENI which caused to throw an error

`Lambda was not able to create an ENI in the VPC of the Lambda function because the limit for Network Interfaces has been reached.`

I searched google but couldn't find the best way to solve this issue. Apart from manually deleting these ENIs periodically is there a better way?

Comment: Does the Lambda role have permissions to delete an ENI or only permission to create?

Comment: @MarkB: Interesting, haven't thought about it. It doesn't have delete permission. Let me try giving that permission and see what happens

Comment: @blueskin I'm investigating a similar issue. Where did you get the error you mention in you question?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Mark suggested, the issue was my AWS Lambda didn't have the [DeleteNetworkInterface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteNetworkInterface.html) Action specified in the role(Policy) that the lambda was set to. By giving the appropriate policy the Lambda now detaches and deletes the ENI when done.

```
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:ResetNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction"
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

The official line from AWS (via [their docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html) and a support ticket) is to use the AWS-managed policy `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`.

Excerpt from a private support ticket:

> The role you are using in your Lambda function has an attached policy "AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole", which is an AWS managed policy for VPC-enabled Lambda functions. This policy contains all needed permissions and may be updated in future if new permissions are needed due to updates to the service.

It is also worth noting that it can sometimes take several hours for detached ENIs to be reaped.

Comment: It would be nice if there were some way to clean up those ENI's faster.  It takes quite a while to finish a CF rollback in which ENI's must be cleaned up.  Slows things down a bit when you're working on pipelines.

Comment: Nowadays there is a different setup in play that mitigates this significantly and is generally better, described here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/.

Comment: That's very useful!  Seems like it definitely requires some effort to reconfigure it to work that way (as opposed to the more "traditional" approach).  I'll keep that in mind for future work though!