# Lambda in VPC won't create new ENI after an ENI has been manually detached from subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have run into a problem where my Lambda functions can no longer create new ENI's in a VPC subnet once an ENI has been detached and deleted from that subnet. I have reproduced this on two different VPC's and multiple subnets.

Here are the steps I used to reproduce this:

1. Create a Lambda function and associate it with a VPC and a subnet.
2. Execute the Lambda function which will cause it to create a new ENI in the subnet. The function is able to access an RDS database in the VPC.
3. Manually detach and delete the ENI from the subnet.
4. Execute the Lambda function again. No ENI will be created. Lambda function is unable to access RDS database.

I repeated these steps across multiple subnets in two VPC's and a now Lambda functions are unable to create new ENI's in any of those subnets.

It seemed like the VPC subnet was permanently unable to have new ENI's created by Lambda functions but after letting things sit overnight I ran the function again this morning and it was able to create an ENI. AWS must have an automated process that cleaned something up. Even so, I tested detaching and deleting again and I'm back in the state where the Lambda function won't create a new ENI.

Not sure what is going on here. I'm not selecting 'Force Detach' when detaching the ENI. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ENIs are only created on Lambda cold starts. I'm guessing you are hitting a Lambda function that is still warm after you have manually deleted the ENI.

Comment: But if I delete the Lambda function and recreate it in that same VPC and subnet the new function isn't able to create ENI's. Shouldn't deleting and recreating the function cause a cold start?

Comment: Yeah that doesn't sound right. Are you changing the IAM role assigned to the function?

Comment: Why do you need to delete the ENIs? What problem are you trying to solve by doing so?

Comment: @MarkB I was using the same IAM role but I just tried creating a new function and a new IAM role but using the same VPC and subnet and still not getting an ENI.

Comment: @MattHouser I'm using the Serverless.com framework and during development we frequently build up and tear down Lambda functions. The Serverless.com framework uses Cloudformation scripts to do that. This is the first time I'm using Lambda's in a VPC because we need to access an RDS instance. I noticed this problem after I tried to tear down and rebuild. To try and figure this out I'm manually detaching the ENI's to reproduce what was happening with the Cloudformation scripts.

Comment: The Lambda ENIs will probably be cleaned up by AWS automatically. I don't think there's a need for you to do it yourself.

Comment: The ENIs don't get created by serverless or CloudFormation. They're going to be created on-demand (normally) as Lambda functions execute. As your Lambda function scales, AWS will allocate more ENIs. Tearing down the CloudFormation/serverless stack won't delete them.

Comment: Just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990747/lambda-creating-eni-everytime-it-is-invoked-hitting-limit

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299662/aws-lambda-created-eni-not-deleting-while-deletion-of-stack

Comment: So it looks like (a) your Lambda role needs permission to delete ENIs, and (b) if you delete the role before they're deleted, then you must delete them manually, otherwise, AWS should clean them up with enough time.

Comment: @MattHouser Cloudformation does 'try' to remove them.

DELETE_IN_PROGRESS: "CloudFormation is waiting for NetworkInterfaces associated with the Lambda Function to be cleaned up."

The stack gets stuck there. This is why I got into the situation of manually deleting the ENI's and then discovered that new ENI's couldn't be created in that subnet once doing so.

Answer (score 7):

From the research I have done this afternoon it appears this is a limitation of Lambda functions running in a VPC and has been for over a year. There is a six hour delay in the clean up of ENI's after a Lambda function has been deleted. My manual detachment and deletion of the ENI made things worse because it seems the ENI isn't really removed until after the six hour delay. The manual deletion seems to put the ENI in some sort of orphaned state that prevents new ENI's from being created in that subnet until after AWS has cleaned up the old one.

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/4fncrl/dangling_enis_after_deleting_an_invpc_lambda_with/

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5767

So it seems currently the only solution to forcing clean up is to delete the ENI and the subnet it was in. :-/

I let my serverless remove command run for a long time (without me speeding things along by manually deleting the ENI) and it did eventually finish but it took 40 minutes. The ENI was left behind but everything else was cleaned up. I imagine in six hours that ENI will disappear.

Comment: Matthew, this seems to be still happening as it happens to me. Did you make any additional progress since last year, or is it simply a bug AWS are not fixing?

Comment: Back in November 2017 I exchanged e-mails with a 'Senior Developer Advocate' on the Lambda team and he said "The 40 minute time issue is being worked on". I've tried e-mailing him again since then and got no response. I've also opened support tickets through our AWS business support contract and the only response I get is "We are working on it".  :-/

Answer (score 3):

I recently faced a similar issue. I couldn't delete sg or subnets since they were being used by other stacks. I figured out if I force lambda to cold start, it might create new eni. To test this I allocated max memory and timeout. It worked.

Comment: This is a great workaround. Changing the memory allocation to max appears to cause all underlying containers to be dropped, and subsequent invocations to be cold start.

Comment: This did trigger the ENI to be rebuilt