# Java code in AWS Lambda (inside VPC) not working

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

we have Java code deployed in Lambda AWS. This code access a service in the VPC. we have set the VPC and security group alright. the function starts working. However often after a few days, the function can not access the WEB service from VPC and times out.

if I just go change the VPC to some other VPC, save the function, and then save again to the same VPC (Which was set originally). the functions starts working again. we are also accessing the same service in python code. but here I don't see this issue.

we thought static code might be issued in the Java code. but later figure that this is happening because of VPC issues

class level:
private  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

inside a method. This connection is timed out

```
String url = clientURL + "/users/user/_search";
logger.info("client URL : {}", clientURL);
String jsonString = this.getMatchQuery("email", email);

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Request request = new Request.Builder().
    url(url)
    .post(RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonString))
    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: Be aware that AWS might reuse the same Lambda instance across invocations and therefore the client could be reused as well. I doubt it's the root cause of your problem, but this knowledge might be useful.

Comment: well, every day the Java code stop working from about 11:00 AM EST.  now even setting/resetting VPC is also not working.

Comment: check if the ENI is not getting exhausted, lambda role should also have vpc resource permission.

Comment: how should I check this? it has VPC resource permission because it works half of the time. How should I check that ENIs are getting exhausted

Comment: No clues in the stackTrace, errorMessage?

Comment: since this function tries to get the data from the web service which is in VPC, there is always error about the socket connection time out.

Comment: here is the lambda function stack trace:
 total inventories : connect timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl

Comment: apparently problem discussed and solution also noted in the below
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759936/lambda-in-vpc-wont-create-new-eni-after-an-eni-has-been-manually-detached-from?rq=1

Comment: looks like the ENI is created for a security group that we assign to the lambda function. so when lambda is called, the ENI is retrieved using the security name. in case, same security group is assigned to more than one lambda. There might be confliction and either one of the functions might run out of the connection.